# Find a money amount specified in a email and print it next to a str

Tags: python, api, gmail-api

I've been trying to make an API that automates a detector for new transaction emails in my Gmail Account, and now it detects all the emails coming from my bank that are related to a transaction send to myself, but it prints the whole email (which contains the money expressed like this "$" in a certain point of the email), and I want it that the script detects the money amount and then prints a string with it like this for example

```
print("Transaction Recieved"," $" ,moneyAmount,"!")
```

The Messages Filter part of the script

```
#Messages Filter
        message_count = 50
        for message in messages[:message_count]:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            email = (msg['snippet'])
            if "Datos de la transferencia que recibiste Monto $" in email:
                service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()
                print(f'{email}\n')
```

And I can't figure how to make it so it detects the money amount that is expressed inside the bank's email.

I tried to do an attempt of making it to detect a string pattern of a value of 1 digit that could go from 1 to 9 followed by a "." and after that a value of 3 digits that could go from 001 to 999 and then print the whole value, but it didn't work so I'm out of ideas.

Here's my attempt of making it

```
#Messages Filter
        message_count = 50
        for message in messages[:message_count]:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            email = (msg['snippet'])
            if "Datos de la transferencia que recibiste Monto $" in email:
                value = re.findall(r'$\d{1}.\d{3}', email)
                service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()
                print(f'{email}\n')
                print(f'{value}\n')
```

[The amount of money is displayed like this in the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZ2t.png)
[And this is like directly from the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH3SG.png)

If someone with an idea could help me, I would be very grateful.

P.S.:Btw if you see something that you don't understand because of the language, it's because it's in Spanish, but it's mostly in strings so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions? (the `re` library is part of Python, no installation required)  It appears you could just try to match something like `r'\$\d+(?:.\d{3})+(?:,\d+)?'`.  Have a look at a site like this to experiment with other regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/BtSglx/1

Comment: @Grismar I used the string pattern of the regular expression that you gave me and it worked!
Thank You so Much!

Comment: If you feel that answers your question, you should consider writing an answer presenting your solution and accept it as the answer to your own question, or close/delete the question, since an answer is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to replace the string pattern that I was using for the re and it ended like this

```
re.findall(r'\$\d+(?:.\d{3})+(?:,\d+)?', email)
```

Insted of this

```
re.findall(r'$\d{1}.\d{3}', email)
```

Thanks to @Grismar for the answer

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer as well - if you accept the answer with the checkmark, your question will no longer be marked 'unanswered' :)